# How to fill a DataSet with specific data

Tags: c#, database, dataset

I am new to DataSets and I am wondering how I can fill my DataSet with data without just using the Fill-Function. This is my code

```
using (var dataset = new U2ZFDataSet())
{
    dataset.Relations.Add("stoerung_station", dataset.stoerung.Columns["fknrStationen"], dataset.stationen.Columns["nrStationen"]);
    DataRelation rel = dataset.Relations["stoerung_station"];

    foreach (DataRow row in dataset.Tables["stoerung"].Rows)
    {
        foreach (DataRow station in row.GetChildRows(rel))
        {
            list.Add(station["Bezeichnung"].ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that

```
dataset.Tables["stoerung"].Rows
```

is always 0 because I dont have any data in my DataSet. But how do I fill my DataSet with data. Lets say I have a column "Date" and I want it to be filled with all the rows where date < today.

What am I missing?

Comment: why not do a `dataset.Tables["stoerung"].Rows.Add(new object[]{your_row_contents_here});` first?

Comment: What I mean is. I already have my database filled with data. Table "stoerung" has around 100'000 rows. I dont want to add rows. I want to retrieve them. But `dataset.Tables["stoerung"].Rows` seems to be always 0 and I dont know why.

Comment: Try following : foreach(DataRow row in dataset.Tables["stoerung"].AsEnumerable)
{
   Console.WriteLine(row.Field<DateTime>("Date").ToString());
}

Comment: how have you populated your dataset with the rows you are trying to iterate through?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this MSDN tutorial on using (strongly typed) datasets:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171884(v=vs.90).aspx

It is part of a library of more in-depth tutorials found here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxsa23t6(v=vs.90).aspx

I recommend these because it sounds to me like you have a basic expectation that datasets magically fill with data when created to look like some database that may be in your project. DataSets and databases are two separate things - the dataset is a model of some of the database and is a client side code entity; you have to actually fill it with data from the database using a separate set of classes called dataadapters (in those tutorials, tableadapters = strongly typed wrappers around a dataadapter)

If you follow the first tutorial, it'll take about 15 minutes and at the end you'll have a fully working application that can read and write data from a database. You can then throw away the test app and apply what you've learned to your current app. I don't recommend learning by trying to adapt the tutorial to your situation immediately; take an hour out of your life to do a one time run through exactly as they say, using their sample database etc and then have a go at applying the concepts to your app